# Como faço para saber se a paginação foi clicada no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

estou com um problema preciso enviar um parâmetro de uma view para outra. Até aí beleza está funcionando, porém estou tendo problemas na paginação, pois ele dá erro nesse parâmetro que preciso enviar, para resolver isso preciso deixar esse parâmetro `nulo`, porém para isso teria que verificar se pagina foi clicada.
Tem como saber isso?

Segue método do controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{     
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $btn = $request->query();

    $products = DB::table('products')->when($search , function ($query) use ($search ) {
                    return $query->where('name', 'like', '%'. $search .'%' )
                            ->orWhere('detalhe', 'like', '%'. $search .'%')
                            ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                })->paginate(5);


    return view('products.index', compact('products','btn'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1)* 5);

    //dd($btn);
//        $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);
//        
//        return view('products.index', compact('products','btn'))
//                ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) -1)* 5);
}
```

uma coisa que poderia servir é capturar a page atual, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: pra pegar a página atual, use `$pagina = $request->query('page');` - se quiser pegar a anterior, basta subtrair 1 ou somar 1 se quiser a página seguinte

Comment: isso mesmo que eu queria obrigado Diego.